# If $f$ is analytic where $f$ is represented as $f=g.h$ where $g$ is analytic . From here can we conclude that $h$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

If $f$ is analytic, where  $f$ is represented as $f=g \cdot h,$ where $g$ is analytic. From here can we conclude that $h$ is analytic?

Comment: hmmm, accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No take $f\equiv 1$ , $g=x$ and $h=\frac{1}{x}$.
This only works when you allow to observe the limits, without this there are still counter examples.

In fact we can't even conclude that $h$ is continuous anywhere, when $f\equiv 0$ and $g\equiv 0$ you may chose $h$ as any function. To make it not to complicated we just look at the real case (a function is analytic when it locally has a converging taylor series). Chosing $f=0$, $g=0$ and 
$$h=\begin{cases}
0 & x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
1 & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
\end{cases}$$
gives us a counter example where $h$ is discontinuous everywhere.

As Martin wanted some positive results:
When $f(x_0)\neq 0$ and $g(x_0)\neq 0$ we know that $h$ must be at least locally bounded at $x_0$.

When we say that $g\neq 0$ then 
$$\frac{f}{g}$$ is complex differentiable which mean that 
$$\frac{f}{g}=h$$ is complex differentiable and hence analytic.

When $f(x_0)=0$ is a zero of finite order, which means that there exists an $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^k}\neq 0$$
And $g$ has a zero of the same order (or lower) in $x_0$ then $h$ is analytic in $x_0$.

Writing $g$ and $f$ as power series gives this result.

Comment: In what sense do you really have $f = gh$ in your first example? And what about positive results?

Comment: @Martin made some changes

Comment: Thanks. The points I was trying to convey: 1. the equality holds in the [field of meromorphic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) 2. If $g(x_0) \neq 0$ then $h$ *is* analytic in a neighborhood of $x_0$. More generally: if $f(x_0)$ vanishes to at least the same finite order as $g(x_0)$ then $h$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $x_0$ by [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem).

Comment: @Martin ok added that stuff thanks again :)

Comment: $z$, $1/z$,$1$ does not work as counter example?

Comment: @Tsotsi in a strict sense they don't work, as $\frac{1}{z}$ is not defined at zero and hence is not a function on the domain